# creating new column using regex if certain keywords are found in other column values

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe, nlp

I have dataframe (df) column called A which is string

```
 index   A
----------------------------
  0      boy_was_born_in_2010
  1      men_was_born_in_1997
  2      girl_this_is_2022
  3      this_is_a_lady
  4      how_tall_is_this_boy
  5      girl_is_studying
```

Now I wrote a code which would identify specific words like boy, girl, men, lady if it found that keyword in the column A create a new column B, given below
which is if the string A contain boy then B will have Kid as a value and contain men->Male, girl->Kid, lady->female

```
 index   A                         B
------------------------------------------
  0      boy_was_born_in_2010      Kid
  1      men_was_born_in_1997      Male
  2      girl_this_is_2022         Kid
  3      this_is_a_lady            Female
  4      how_tall_is_this_boy      Kid
  5      girl_is_studying          Kid
```

I have used the following code

```py
df['B']=df.A.str.findall('boy').transform(''.join).replace('boy','Kid')
```

this is working fine but when i apply it for other rows than the previously applied value which is the above somehow gets undo, moreover I dont think this is a optimized way

also tried this

```py
df['B'] = df['A'].replace(to_replace ='^boy\W', value = 'Kid', regex = True) # not working
```

if you have anyother way of doing it please suggest
I'am a complete beginner just started working on NLP projects

Comment: What is supposed to happen if you have a string that contains multiple matches? E.g. `boy meets girl`? Or is this not possible given the actual data?

Comment: In other words, is it the first keyword occurrence that sets the category type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an example with multiple matches:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': ['boy_was_born_in_2010',
  'men_was_born_in_1997',
  'girl_this_is_2022',
  'this_is_a_lady',
  'how_tall_is_this_boy',
  'girl_is_studying',
  'boy meets men']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

                      A
0  boy_was_born_in_2010
1  men_was_born_in_1997
2     girl_this_is_2022
3        this_is_a_lady
4  how_tall_is_this_boy
5      girl_is_studying
6         boy meets men
```

Set up a dict for mapping, use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) on `pattern` with alternatives, [`sqeeuze`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html) the result, and finally apply [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
a_dict = {'boy':'Kid',
          'men':'Male',
          'girl':'Kid',
          'lady':'Female'}

pattern = '(' + '|'.join(list(a_dict)) + ')'
df['B'] = df.A.str.extract(pattern).squeeze().map(a_dict)

print(df)

                      A       B
0  boy_was_born_in_2010     Kid
1  men_was_born_in_1997    Male
2     girl_this_is_2022     Kid
3        this_is_a_lady  Female
4  how_tall_is_this_boy     Kid
5      girl_is_studying     Kid
6         boy meets men     Kid
```

Above method will only get you the *first* match. E.g. `boy` -> `Kid` for last string. If you want to get *all* matches, we can use something like this:

```
temp = df.A.str.extractall(pattern).squeeze().map(a_dict)
df['B'] = temp.groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)

print(df)

                      A          B
0  boy_was_born_in_2010        Kid
1  men_was_born_in_1997       Male
2     girl_this_is_2022        Kid
3        this_is_a_lady     Female
4  how_tall_is_this_boy        Kid
5      girl_is_studying        Kid
6         boy meets men  Kid, Male
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first occurrence sets the category type, you can consider using the following solution based on `numpy.select`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':["boy_was_born_in_2010","men_was_born_in_1997","girl_this_is_2022","this_is_a_lady","how_tall_is_this_boy","girl_is_studying"]})

condlist = [
    df['A'].str.contains(r'(?<![^\W\d_])(?:boy|girl)s?(?![^\W\d_])', case=False, regex=True),
    df['A'].str.contains(r'(?<![^\W\d_])m[ea]n(?![^\W\d_])', case=False, regex=True),
    df['A'].str.contains(r'(?<![^\W\d_])lad(?:y|ies)(?![^\W\d_])', case=False, regex=True),
]

choicelist = ['Kid', 'Male', 'Female']
df['B'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                      A       B
0  boy_was_born_in_2010     Kid
1  men_was_born_in_1997    Male
2     girl_this_is_2022     Kid
3        this_is_a_lady  Female
4  how_tall_is_this_boy     Kid
5      girl_is_studying     Kid
```

**Notes**

- `(?<![^\W\d_])(?:boy|girl)s?(?![^\W\d_])` - matches `boy` / `boys` / `girl` / `girls` not enclosed with any letters (identified as `Kid`)
- `(?<![^\W\d_])m[ea]n(?![^\W\d_])` - `man` or `men` not enclosed with any letters (identified as `Male`)
- `(?<![^\W\d_])lad(?:y|ies)(?![^\W\d_])` - `lady` or `ladies` not enclosed with any letters  (identified as `Female`).